# Vanishing cohomologies for curve in surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, sheaf-cohomology

Let $C$ be a smooth irreducible complex curve on a complex surface $S$, defined as the zero locus of a section of a complex line bundle $L$. Note the normal bundle is the restriction $N_{C/S}=L|_C$. I would expect vanishing of the sheaf cohomologies $h^1(L)=h^2(L)=0$, when some nice properties hold of $S$.

For example, if the anti-canonical divisor of $S$ is effective, then $h^2(L)=0$ since
\begin{equation}
H^2(L)\cong H^0(L^*\otimes K_S) \subseteq H^0(L^*)=0\,,
\end{equation}
where the first step used Serre duality, the second the fact the anti-canonical bundle $K_S^*$ corresponds to an effective divisor, and the third that $L^*$ does not correspond to an effective divisor.

Can one show that $h^1(L)=0$ under this assumption? If not, does it hold under stronger assumptions, e.g. when the anti-canonical divisor of $S$ is nef, or if $S$ is weak Fano?

Comment: The second cohomology always vanishes, since dim $C = 1$.

Comment: @JohnBrevik You are right; this was a mistake in notation. I should say that $C$ is the zero locus of a section of a complex line bundle $L$ on $S$, so that $N_{C/S}=L|_C$. Then it's possible $h^2(L) \neq0$. I will edit the question, thanks.

Comment: @diracula Come again? You can have $h^2(S,L) \neq 0$, but $h^2(C,L|_C)$ will always vanish. Your title suggests that you are interested in the cohomology of the curve, but the question suggests that you might have only mentioned the curve because $L$ arises as its normal bundle, and are in fact interested in $h^i(S,L)$; is this correct? In any case, your question will probably depend both on the geometry of the surface and how the curve sits in it; for example if $C$ is the exceptional divisor of a point blowup, its normal bundle will be anti-ample.

Comment: @TabesBridges The point is $h^0(S,L)-1$ is the dimension of deformations of $C$ in $S$. If $h^1(S,L)=h^2(S,L)=0$ then $h^0$ equals the index which is simply $g(C)-K_S \cdot C$. This is true for the example of e.g. the exceptional divisor of a point blowup of $\mathbb{P}^2$; I would guess only effectiveness of $C$ is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $S=\mathbb{F}_2$, the Hirzebruch surface and let $C$ be the unique rational curve with $C^2=-2$. Then, $H^1(\mathcal{O}_S(C))\neq 0$, while $-K_S$ is effective and $S$ is weak Fano.

Comment: Coincidentally I just thought of this counterexample, then came to post it here and saw your answer!